# Tengo un If que funcionaba bien hace apenas un día, ahora ya no funciona y no se porque

Tags: java, if

La parte que falla es validar los caracteres que ingresa el usuario, lo hacia correctamente y ahora ya no valida nada, no entra el if nunca. Este es la parte del código que valida los caracteres:

```
private void jTxtappKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        char tecleada=evt.getKeyChar();//obtiene el caracter tecleado
        if((tecleada <'a' || tecleada>'z') && (tecleada <'A' || tecleada>'Z')&& tecleada !=32 && tecleada !=8 && tecleada ==164 && tecleada ==165 && tecleada ==161 && tecleada ==160 && tecleada ==162 && tecleada ==163 && tecleada ==130 && tecleada ==181 && tecleada ==144 && tecleada ==214 && tecleada ==233 && tecleada ==224)
        {
            evt.consume(); //no permite consumar la escritura en caso de no cumplir con el if
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se permiten dígitos en apellidos","Formato Incorrecto", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo puede darse nunca que `tecleada == 164` y `tecleada == 165` A LA VEZ? Si haces un AND (`&&`), p. ej. `a && b`, eso solo valdrá *true* si tanto a como b valen *true*. Revisa tu expresión.

Comment: Probablemente te ayudará si la simplificas; dividiendo la expresión en funciones (uno que te devuelva si `tecleada` es una letra entre `a` y `z`, otro que te diga si es una letra entre `A` y `Z`, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el metodo `Character.isDigit(char c)` de la clase Character para comprar si el carácter es un número o una letra este método devuelve true si el chat que has introducido es un dígito .

Aquí te dejo un link con más 
 información:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/character_isdigit.htm

Espero que te sirva